# SP2-0306: Invalid option. while connecting to DB via shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sqlplus

I have a shell script that queries the database by connecting to it via sqlplus but i'm getting Invalid Option error .Below is my script.

```
set -x
TodayDate=`date +%d-%m-%Y`

read_sql_stmt()
{
        typeset stmt=$1
        typeset login=$2
        echo "
                set feedback off verify off heading off pagesize 0
                $stmt;
                exit
                " | sqlplus -s login
}
#USER_PASS="bnpqa/bnpqa@MTS12C"
echo $USER_PASS
dnsmDate=`read_sql_stmt "select distinct(to_char(trunc(nse_update_date),'DD-MM-YYYY')) FROM DRV_NSE_SECURITY_MASTER" "$USER_PASS"`

echo "$dnsmDate"
if [ $TodayDate -gt $dnsmDate ]
then
echo "Success"
fi;
```

Below is the output when i'm debugging using set -x

```
+++ date +%d-%m-%Y
++ TodayDate=13-10-2017
++ echo bnpqa/bnpqa@MTS12C
bnpqa/bnpqa@MTS12C
+++ read_sql_stmt 'select distinct(to_char(trunc(nse_update_date),'\''DD-MM-YYYY'\'')) FROM DRV_NSE_SECURITY_MASTER' bnpqa/bnpqa@MTS12C
+++ typeset 'stmt=select distinct(to_char(trunc(nse_update_date),'\''DD-MM-YYYY'\'')) FROM DRV_NSE_SECURITY_MASTER'
+++ typeset login=bnpqa/bnpqa@MTS12C
+++ echo '
                set feedback off verify off heading off pagesize 0
                select distinct(to_char(trunc(nse_update_date),'\''DD-MM-YYYY'\'')) FROM DRV_NSE_SECURITY_MASTER;
                exit
                '
+++ sqlplus -s login
++ dnsmDate='
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]'
++ echo '
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]'

SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
++ '[' 13-10-2017 -gt SP2-0306: Invalid option. Usage: 'CONN[ECT]' '[{logon|/|proxy}' '[AS' '{SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM}]' '[edition=value]]' where '<logon>' ::= '<username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]' '<proxy>' ::= '<proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]' ']'
./FileUploadStatus.sh: line 21: [: 13-10-2017: integer expression expected
```

Although i'm able to connect to DB directly from my terminal via sqlplus username/password@DBNAME.

Comment: You forgot to use `$login` and instead just used `login` in your function

Comment: oops my bad,thanks man.

Comment: but now when i'm comparing dates it's throwing an error "integer expression expected" , i read somewhere that we can compare dates like this.

Comment: sorted out that as well , used '>' instead of  '-gt' .